# Url only with string ID : URL Routing in asp.net 4.0 Webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, url-routing, asp.net-4.0

I previously created a url like this

```
www.mydomain.com/brand/nikkon  using URL routing asp.net 4(webforms)

RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("brandRoute","brand/{Name}","~/Viewbrand.aspx");
```

Now I want to create a url like this

```
www.mydomain.com/nikkon    by using URL routing asp.net 4(webforms)
```

please help.

optional: Is it possible by using urlrewriter.net

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("brandRoute","/{Name}","~/Viewbrand.aspx");
```